# Trouble with installing VMWare-Player 3

Tags: installation, vmware

After downloading the VMware-Player 3 from the VMware site I wanted to install it, however because I used an older VMware-Player the new installer wanted to uninstall this older version first.

After starting the uninstall process I had trouble with my machine and it shut down - now I have no option to uninstall the older VMware-Player and every time I want to install Player 3.0, I get an error-message.

Is it possible to clean up the rest of the older installation so that I can install the new version of VMWare Player?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning up the uninstall with [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com).